# php copy() on same server different domains

Tags: php

I am trying to run.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    copy(
         '/var/www/vhosts/domain1.com/httpdocs/new/uploads/orderform_artwork_files/0900716d2ffdcb8.png', 
         '/var/www/vhosts/domain2.com/httpdocs/new/uploads/orderform_artwork_files/0900716d2ffdcb8.png'
    );
```

It is the part of a big picture where I have to clone data of one domain to other, server is same.

Problem is, it is not copying the files, and there are no errors.

**EDIT**

here is the warning message I am getting

```
Warning: copy() [function.copy]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/vhosts/domain2.com/httpdocs/new/uploads/orderform_artwork_files/2e68a7b645a91d9.xls) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/domain1.com/httpdocs/:/tmp/) in /var/www/vhosts/domain1.com/httpdocs/new/cron/cloneToCCS.php5 on line 155
```

Comment: This most likely has to do with permissions or an open basedir restriction. Can you put `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your script, maybe then you'll get some output?

Comment: yes, it displayed the same error you mentioned `Warning: copy() [function.copy]: open_basedir restriction in effect.` is there any solution to this? MySQL is able to insert data in other DB

Comment: yes, and this is part of a cron job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by

http://www.names.co.uk/support/servers/plesk_11/1447-adding_a_location_to_phps_open_basedir_restriction_plesk_11.html

I hope this will solve any other fellow SO user

Answer (score 2):

Try editting your `/var/www/vhosts/domain1.com/conf/vhost.conf` file. If it doesn't exist, create it. Then add the following line:

```
php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/domain1.com/httpdocs:/var/www/vhosts/domain2.com/httpdocs"
```

Save the file and then reload your apache configuration by running this command on the command line assuming you have priviledges:

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/websrvmng -u --vhost-name=domain1.com
```

Comment: hmm, i tried your method couple of times, few times with some additional tweaks but still nothing